# ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '@localhost.localdomain' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql

I have typed this mysql command by mistake:

```
INSERT INTO `alias` (`source`, `destination`) VALUES ("@localhost.localdomain", "@localhost"), ("@localhost", "email1@domain1.com");
```

I would like remove or update the email address `email1@domain1.com` from mysql database because when I try insert:

```
INSERT INTO `alias` (`source`, `destination`) VALUES ("@localhost.localdomain", "@localhost"), ("@localhost", "goodaccount@domain.com");
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '@localhost.localdomain' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Please show CREATE TABLE for the `alias` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field `source` is primary key in `alias` table. And you can't insert same value in PK field again and again. You are getting this error as you are inserting same value in PK field again

You can update email like this

```
UPDATE alias SET destination = 'goodaccount@domain.com' WHERE source  = "@localhost";
```

For delete

```
DELETE FROM alias WHERE destination = 'email1@domain1.com' AND source  = "@localhost";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your insert. You insert TWO!! rows, but you need only one.

```
INSERT INTO `alias` (`source`, `destination`) VALUES  ("@localhost", "goodaccount@domain.com");
DELETE FROM `alias` WHERE `destination` = 'email1@domain1.com' and `source` = '@localhost.localdomain';
```